# How to perform bi-directional communication between client and server

Tags: node.js, sockets, angular7

I want to take three inputs on the frontend- start_val, end_val, and increment_val and post these values to the backend in real time. On the server I want to perform some operation and send it back to client.

I'm confused on how to proceed.

Example Input - start_val = 10, end_val = 50, increment_val = 10( This s taken from the client side .

Output = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] returned back to the client from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Real-Time Web App(Bidirectional communication), you can use **Socket.io** in your Node.js server

Basically create a *Node.js App(with Socket.io and Express.js)* and consume socket endpoints with your *Client App(Angular7)*

[This article](https://alligator.io/angular/socket-io/) explains it in detail that how to create a Real-Time App with Node.js, Socket.IO and Angular7

Comment: Thank you Sir for your kind response. I was able to achieve it, but this seems like a very god article. Much appreciated!! Now I'm stuck with d3 chart :(